# Camtasia: two independent simultaneous recordings?

Tags: multiple-monitors, recording, camtasia

Can Camtasia 7 record two independent blocks of my desktop at the same time?

I've got four monitors, and I want to record the events happening concurrently on the outer monitors without recording what's happening on the inner monitors during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just record the whole desktop (all 4 monitors), and afterwards crop out the areas of the screen that you want.